# How to get issue closed status from bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

I have integrated BigQuery in my Firebase project, how should I get the issue closed state ?

I read [Export Firebase Crashlytics data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export) carefully before submitting a question.

Answer (score 4):

*firebaser here*

Looking into the [BigQuery schema](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export), I couldn’t find a field providing the status of the crash report. It seems like a reasonable request though, so I filed a feature request on your behalf to include this information. Keep an eye on our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) to get updates on new features and fixes.